# How can I display a .docx file in an app?

Tags: android, webview, doc

From what I've read its possible if you do it via WebView. The thing is I need to grab the file locally, I don't have internet connection. How can I use WebView to display the document offline? Code example would help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I use WebView to display the document offline?

You can't. The only way to use `WebView` to view a document format like that is to upload it to some service like Google Docs. `WebView` cannot directly display DOCX any more than it can directly display Photoshop PSD files.

You are welcome to open the document in third-party Android apps that support DOCX format, offering to help users install one from the Play Store if they do not already have one. This is free for you and fairly easy to implement.

Otherwise, I hope you have a hundred developer-years or so to write your own DOCX parser and renderer.